# Add Columns in DataGrid : Flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

I have one Datagrid in Flex. In datagrid there are 4 columns like mark1,mark2,mark3,Total. When i enter mark1,mark2,mark3 that time i want to update total.

How can i do this??

Please help me